# How do I get sponsored posts with Facebook using the API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I wonder if it was possible with the facebook api to be able to filter and display only publications that are **sponsored** ?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Page Ads Posts endpoint: {page-id}/ads_posts

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/ads_posts/

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer, I'm looking to make a site similar to bigspy.com I look at the doc but I don't really find what I want to do